# New Relic Custom FACETS

Tags: newrelic, newrelic-platform, newrelic-synthetics

In new relic, APM External services we can see all http spans and the HTTP.URL which gets invoked

I want to add a panel in my dashboard to track this for all my micro services.
But instead of URL i want to replace it with a custom client name that i want to code as key/value.
That will be mine client/HAIP map.

What is the best way do this. I'm super new to new relic.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there aren’t too many values to map out then one solution is to just do a [NRQL Facet Cases As](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/query-your-data/nrql-new-relic-query-language/get-started/nrql-syntax-clauses-functions/#facet-cases-as-label)

Comment: Actually there are about 20. That's why i wanted a clean way to do it in one panel